# How to turn my screen black and then turn it back on on command?

Tags: windows-10, autohotkey, screensaver

I need to find a way to make my pc (windows 10) screen turn black, without turning the computer off (or putting it to sleep) and then turn it back on on command.

This is because I need t make a macrorecorder script, but I want to conceal some moves by turning the screen black and then turning the screen back on when the script reaches a certain point.

All the methods I have found so far work like a screensaver so when I do any move after turning the screen black, it turns back on because of said move. I've tried the app "BlackTop", and also writing a script with AutoHotKey but that also just turns on the screensaver.

Any help will be much appreciated

Comment: I know this isn't an answer to your q; but it kind of sounds like you're recording this to present to other people? If that's the case you could also consider a video recording + editing. CamStudio is OK but has no real editing capabilities. Screen2Gif has very limited editing but can record to video if you have ffmpeg. ActivePresenter has an unlimited free trial version with direct screen (and audio) recording and a *very* full-featured and intuitive editor (I use it all the time). Or if you upload a full recording to YouTube it has a blur editor that you can use to blur info in videos.

Comment: Btw, just to be clear, for your black screen approach, you want to continue interacting with things (that you can't necessarily see) when the screen is black, right?

Comment: (FYI: [This](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=QfGsg__jlo4) took about 5 minutes in ActivePresenter, if that's what you're after.)

Comment: Thank you for your comment!

Yes I need to interact with things behind the black screen. Basically I will have a photo up, with directions (press button 1 for X presentation, press button 2 for Y presentation type of thing, it's for a museum exhibition and the visitors choose what they want to see) and from there I need to have the black screen until the video is on full screen mode and starts playing.

I will check Active Presenter, sounds promising!

Comment: Well actually, and this is a bit different from your approach, but I've also got a fair amount of experience with video-based art and digital signage. One possible alternate, if you've got the budget for it, is a display with either an ethernet or serial based remote control (I know the Samsung digital signage monitors have ethernet control, for example) that lets you power the display on and off (or change video sources) remotely. Then you could automate turning the display itself on and off from the PC; I know there's got to be free show control sw that can do it, or find a programmer. :D

Comment: Yet another idea along those lines: There's also products that might even be able to take the PC out of the mix completely with easy-ish integration directly into custom button panels. E.g. there's a company BrightSign that makes digital signage players in the $300-$1000 range; although I don't know know about the black screen feature (you'd have to tell them your use case to see if they can offer a solution) but I feel like it can be done.

Comment: In any case keywords for technologies here are "digital signage" -- the advertising display market, as it turns out, has a ton of applications in the art and video presentation market, but they don't often get tapped into because nobody thinks to look for signage solutions when they're coming from the art side. Heck, the Samsung Smart TV's have completely self-contained playlist management with video players, web players, scheduling, automation, ethernet control, remote management, literally a full solution plus some, and nobody ever notices, lol. The old ones even had built in Flash players.

Comment: Again, thanks a lot for your suggestions! I can't turn the screen completely off because then the screen's logo shows up ( I tried it) so that's not an option

A question about ActivePresenter: Does the software actually runs, or it just records my screen as a viedo? because I need things to actually run in order to control the laser projector properly

Comment: Ahhh, I see now; unfortunately ActivePresenter just records video. I didn't realize you also needed the *effects* of your recorded macros to happen live. Hm; do you have a monitor that you can remotely switch the input source on? Maybe you could have a black video source connected to another input, then switch sources? That could avoid the logo. In any case, crossing recorded video off the list kinda kills a lot of my ideas... maybe you could find a way to record both the macro *and* the video, and play the video (somehow) while the macro runs on another display, to fake it?

Comment: If  I had two screens then my problem wouldn't exist because the software that controls the laser projector and plays the video has an option to put the video on a second screen, full screen and all by default.

Unfortunately I don't have a second screen, so I have to find a way to enable laser projection and start the video, without the process being seen by the visitors. I'm really stuck with this. 

Is there a way to make the screensaver not to deactivate with movement but on command?

Answer (score 1):

SoftwareOK's [IsMyLcdOK](https://www.softwareok.com/?seite=Microsoft/IsMyLcdOK) turns the screen black when <kbd>2</kbd> is pressed. You could then use <kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>Tab</kbd> to switch focus to another program or back. <kbd>Esc</kbd> ends the app.

That said, it might be easier to use two displays, or Windows [Virtual Desktops](https://community.windows.com/en-us/stories/virtual-desktop-windows-10), and record only *one* desktop or display, while moving the step to be hidden to the alternate screen.

Comment: Oh I haven't thought about virtual desktops, I will try it thanks (unfortunately I  don't have the option to use actually two displays)

Answer (score 0):

You could use a command that starts your screensaver with a lock: moves won't remove it. You don't want a complete "black", because you want to be able to stop the script, for instance after problems.

```
cmd /c start /wait scrnsave.scr /s && rundll32 user32.dll,LockWorkStation
```

Comment: I tried that but I need the screen completely black and being able to go back exactly when I want it and I don't think it's possible like that.